# How do I expose a C struct to Python using Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I want to expose the `Point` C struct to Python. The following code compiles, but the struct is not accessible by Python.

Edit: `Point` needs to be accessible to other files in the package as well as pure Python code outside the package.

**The code**

```
// myfile.h

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

```
# blob.pxd

cdef extern from "myfile.h":
    struct Point:
        double x
        double y
```

```
# blob.pyx

# empty file
```

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension(name="blob", sources=["blob.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext,language_level=3))

# call with python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

**The error**

Input 1:

```
import blob
blob.Point
```

Output 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'blob' has no attribute 'Point'
```

Input 2:

```
import blob
blob.__dict__
```

Output 2:

```
{
    '__name__': 'blob',
    '__doc__': None,
    '__package__': '',
    '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x000001ADE4F10DC0>,
    '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='blob', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x000001ADE4F10DC0>, origin='C:\\Users\\aaron\\Desktop\\project\\cython_with_c\\blob.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'),
    '__file__': 'C:\\Users\\aaron\\Desktop\\project\\cython_with_c\\blob.cp38-win_amd64.pyd',
    '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__test__': {}
}
```

Comment: You need to write a `cdef` class that holds a `Point` and has suitable accessors. There are tools that can do it for you (https://github.com/uweschmitt/autowrap) although I haven't used them personally, and if should be pretty easy to do manually in your case

Comment: I thought that I had created a `cdef` class for `Point` in `blob.pxd`. Is this wrong? Are there additional steps? I'm not sure that I understand your comment on suitable accessors. What is a suitable accessor?

Comment: No. You have told Cython about the existence of a C struct called `Point` in `blob.pxd`. That allows you to use the struct in Cython code, but nothing more. A suitable accessor might be a `property` for `x` and a `property` for `y`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of my C struct being used successfully in my pxd file (with some example names):

```
cdef extern from "header_file_containing_struct_definition.h":
    ctypedef struct struct_name_from_header:
        unsigned int device
        unsigned int bus
        unsigned int address
        unsigned int type
        char *devicename
        int connected
```

Note the indentations, just like in normal python, they're critical! I had an obscure error when my indents were not correct.